# "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code in my client App:

```
const socket = io('${location.protocol}//${location.hostname}:8090');
```

is giving me the following error in my browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://${location.protocol}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LRLUtss. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

My client code is run using Node.js via `npm start` so "http://localhost:3000" is automatically refreshed in my browser as I update my code.

Comment: It appears that `${location.protocol}` is not being substituted for in the string.

Comment: @ jfriend00 Thats what I was thinking. Why might that be?

Comment: Perhaps the browser does not support the template literal ES6 feature?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using Safari. Just tried it in Firefox and I'm not getting this error.

Comment: Why not just construct the URL the old fashioned way as a work-around?

Comment: @ jfriend00 I'll do that!

Comment: I don't see you using backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `${location.protocol}` is not being substituted for in the string and thus it's still in the URL when socket.io tries to use the URL.  This could be because the browser does not support that specific ES6 feature.

You can work around it by constructing your URL string the old fashioned way with string addition.

```
const socket = io(location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + ':8090');
```

And, you should also be using backticks as the string delimiters if you expect the substitution to work reliably where it is supported.

Comment: @Baz - The example in your question also doesn't show the use of backticks as the string delimiter.  But, if you weren't using that, then it's hard to see how it would work in any browser so I'm assuming that the backticks were in the real code, just not in what you showed in your question.